# Does he *has* a ball?

Tags: questions, subject-verb-agreement, present-simple, subject-auxiliary-inversion

As we know, third person singular uses "has" instead of "have". But why do you say, "Does he *have* a ball? Yes, he *has* a ball."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In “Does he have it?”, why doesn't ‘have’ agree with ‘he’?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/171977/in-does-he-have-it-why-doesnt-have-agree-with-he)

Comment: The answer to the example question in your post could be "yes, he does have a ball".

Comment: Are you familiar with present simple? Please edit your question to tell us what you already know about present simple.

Comment: In BrEng the question would be "***Has** he got a ball*?" And the short answer would be "**Yes, he** ***has***".

Comment: ... but a more idiomatic answer among Brits would be "Yes, he's got one."

Answer (score 1):

In the sentences "Does he have a ball? Yes, he has a ball." the ***active*** verb agrees with the subject:

In "**Does** he have a ball?", "Does" is the active verb and it agrees with "he"

and

in "Yes, he **has** a ball", "has" is the active verb and agrees with "he".

In "Does he **have** a ball?" "Have" is not an active verb - it is the infinitive. Infinitives do not change.

Using the auxiliary verb "do" as the active verb is how English forms questions.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Present Tense ()

Positive/Affirmative: I have a ball.

Negative: I do not have a ball.

Question: Do I have a ball?

Positive/Affirmative: He  a ball. ('Has' is used with he, she, it etc. - third person singular)

Negative: He    a ball. (NOT has)

Question:  he  a ball? (NOT has)

Simple Present Tense ()

Positive/Affirmative: He . (-s for the third person singular)

Negative: He   . (NOT plays)

Question:  he ? (NOT plays)